# Android how to write the query with a proper projection?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite table called **TermTable** with *id*, *selected*, *term* and *type* columns:

```
static final String TermTable = "Terms";
static final String ID = "id";
static final String Selected = "selected";
static final String Term = "term";
static final String Type = "type";
```

I create the table as follows:

```
private static final String TERM_TABLE_CREATE = "Create table " + TermTable +
    "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    Selected + " VARCHAR(5) ," +
    Term + " VARCHAR(20) ," +
    Type + " VARCHAR(10))";
```

The column "selected" gets the strings "true" or "false".
Now I want to query and get the cursor which gets a string as a *term* and if its *selected* column is true, returns the columns *id* and *type*:

```
public Cursor getFavoriteValues(String term)
{
    String from[] = { "id", "type" };
    String where = ???
    String whereArgs[] = ???
    Cursor cursor = db.query(WordsDB.TermTable, from, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

How are this query attributes defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Cursor getTermValues(String term)
{
    String from[] = { "id", "Type" };
    String where = WordsDB.Selected + "=? AND " + WordsDB.Term + "=?";
    String whereArgs[] = new String[]{ "true", term };
    return db.query(WordsDB.TermTable, from, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out below:

```
public Cursor getTermValues(int index) {
    String from[] = { "id", "Type" };
    String where = WordsDB.ID + "=?"; // You add column as per your Query
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{index + ""};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(WordsDB.TermTable, from, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MD. I found the answer. I posted it.

Answer (score -1):

```
String where = "Selected = '?'"
String whereArgs[] = new String[] { "True" }
```

Comment: But how about the term? I mean String where = "Selected = ? AND Term = ?" and for whereArgs as well?

Comment: Hey, grennis I'm sorry. But I haven't down voted you. Perhaps someone else has done this. I don't know...

Comment: It's a brutal question here on SO. downvotes all around for everyone

Comment: @AliAllahyar for each ? add a value to the String array, `where=" a=?.b=?,c=?` and `whereArg = new String[]{valA,valB, valC}`